# How to auth a user with laravel using microsoft graph api but launch client side function with react

Tags: reactjs, laravel, authentication, microsoft-graph-api

I want to set up authentication with graph api but I have a cors ERROR.

I've already managed to do this on the client side with react but now I'd like to do it on the server side with laravel.

I have already :

- Done all the configuration on azure AD and have all the necessary environment variables.
- Installed the following packages on the laravel side: league/oauth2-client and microsoft/microsoft-graph

First, i've got two routes server side :

```
Route::get('/login', [AuthController::class, 'signin']);
Route::get('/login/callback', [AuthController::class, 'callback']);
```

Here are the Auth controller with sigin and call back function

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Models\User;
use Microsoft\Graph\Graph;
use Microsoft\Graph\Model;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException;

//working
class AuthController extends Controller
{

    public function signin()
    {
        // Initialize the OAuth client
        $oauthClient = new \League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider([
            'clientId' => env('OAUTH_APP_ID'),
            'clientSecret' => env('OAUTH_APP_PASSWORD'),
            'redirectUri' => env('OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI'), //http://localhost:8000/api/login/callback
            'urlAuthorize' => env('OAUTH_AUTHORITY') . env('OAUTH_AUTHORIZE_ENDPOINT'),
            'urlAccessToken' => env('OAUTH_AUTHORITY') . env('OAUTH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT'),
            'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => '',
            'scopes' => env('OAUTH_SCOPES')
        ]);

        $authUrl = $oauthClient->getAuthorizationUrl();

        // Save client state so we can validate in callback
        session(['oauthState' => $oauthClient->getState()]);

        // Redirect to AAD signin page
        return redirect()->away($authUrl);
    }


    public function callback(Request $request)
    {
        // Validate state
        $expectedState = session('oauthState');
        $request->session()->forget('oauthState');
        $providedState = $request->query('state');

        if (!isset($expectedState)) {
            // If there is no expected state in the session,
            // do nothing and redirect to the home page.
            return redirect('/oops1');
        }

        if (!isset($providedState) || $expectedState != $providedState) {
            return redirect('/oops2')
                ->with('error', 'Invalid auth state')
                ->with('errorDetail', 'The provided auth state did not match the expected value');
        }

        // Authorization code should be in the "code" query param
        $authCode = $request->query('code');
        if (isset($authCode)) {
            // Initialize the OAuth client
            $oauthClient = new \League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider([
                'clientId' => env('OAUTH_APP_ID'),
                'clientSecret' => env('OAUTH_APP_PASSWORD'),
                'redirectUri' => env('OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI'),
                'urlAuthorize' => env('OAUTH_AUTHORITY') . env('OAUTH_AUTHORIZE_ENDPOINT'),
                'urlAccessToken' => env('OAUTH_AUTHORITY') . env('OAUTH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT'),
                'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => '',
                'scopes' => env('OAUTH_SCOPES')
            ]);

            try {
                // Make the token request
                $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken('authorization_code', [
                    'code' => $authCode
                ]);

                $graph = new Graph();
                $graph->setAccessToken($accessToken->getToken());

                $user_ms = $graph->createRequest('GET', '/me?$select=displayName,mail,userPrincipalName')
                    ->setReturnType(Model\User::class)
                    ->execute();


                if ($user = User::select('id')->where('username', $user_ms->getUserPrincipalName())->first()) {
                    $u = $user;
                } else {
                    $u = new User();
                    $u->email = $user_ms->getMail();
                    $u->username = $user_ms->getUserPrincipalName();
                    $u->displayName = $user_ms->getDisplayName();
                }

                $u->last_login_at = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
                $u->save();

                Auth::loginUsingId($u->id);
            } catch (IdentityProviderException $e) {
                return redirect('/oops3')
                    ->with('error', 'Error requesting access token')
                    ->with('errorDetail', $e->getMessage());
            }
        }

        return redirect()->intended(env('FRONTEND_APP_URLbis'))
            ->with('error', $request->query('error'))
            ->with('errorDetail', $request->query('error_description'));
    }
}
```

Then, in my react app i have a button who "onClick" made request to signIn

```
import React from 'react';

import axios from 'axios';

const LoginButton = () => {
  const handleLogin = async () => {
    try {
      await axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL2}api/login`,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
        },
      }).then((res) => {
        if (res) {
          console.log('ok');
        } else {
          console.log('err');
        }
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleLogin}>LOGIN</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default LoginButton;
```

On click on "LOGIN", i got the error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?state=2s0b54cf&scope=openid%20profile%20offline_access%20user.read%20contacts.read&response_type=code&approval_prompt=auto&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fapi%2Flogin%2Fcallback&client_id=se' (redirected from 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have tried to return response()->json($authUrl); in the signIn function and to redirect the user to the returned URL in the client side with window.location.replace(response.data.redirectUrl); but i don't thing it's ok to do that.

I have configure the cors.php file with

```
 'paths' => ['api/*', '/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => ['*', '/*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [''],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,
```